# Redirect() and RedirectTo() not working in cloudpages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, redirect

I was using RedirectTo() to redirect from cloudpage to external URL after a data extension update (say "https://www.google.com"). It was working fine yesterday but when I try today, the code is not working. Does anyone know the cause of this issue?

```
%%[
var @mid
SET @mid= RequestParameter('mid')    
SET @value = insertDE("test_DE","mid",@mid)
Redirect("https://www.google.com")

]%%
```

Comment: Are you sure this worked? InsertDE is made to run in email context only. For CloudPages you should be using InsertData

Comment: Also, InsertDE/InsertData will fail, if you attempt to add same record twice

Comment: Hi krish, can you please define "not working"? Are you getting a 500 error or something else?

Comment: Hi Lukas, The insertDE is working and we could see data inserted to the data extension.

Comment: Hi zuzannamj, Couldn't see any error logs but just the redirect function doesn't seems to be executing. On day1 the above code worked and redirected to the next page. On day2, Redirect or RedirectTo() functions doesn't redirect to the specified URL.

Answer (score 2):

Like Lukas mentioned, you should be using the [InsertData](https://ampscript.guide/insertdata/) function on a CloudPage, as the [InsertDE](https://ampscript.guide/insertde/) function is only meant to be used in an email. Additionally, it will fail if you try to insert a duplicate record - that seems to be the only logical explanation why the rest of the script is failing and your redirect isn't working (unless there is further AMPscript that you didn't share that's causing problems).

A couple of improvements to help you out:

1. Change the InsertDE function to InsertData function, or even better, use an [UpsertData](https://ampscript.guide/upsertdata/) function instead - then you won't run into a problem with adding duplicate records (although make sure it will work for your use case)
2. Wrap your AMPscript is a try/catch statement - that way you will be able to do some basic debugging by yourself.

Here's what this could look like:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
try{
</script>

%%[
var @mid
SET @mid= RequestParameter('mid')    
SET @value = insertData("test_DE","mid",@mid)
Redirect("https://www.google.com")
]%%

<script runat="server">
}catch(e){
 Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

Reference: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/09/debugging-ampscript/

Comment: Thanks zuzannamj, As I mentioned in previous comment, the InsertDE is working as expected eventhough the redirection is not working. Understood that InsertDE shouldn't be used based on best practices. May be some instance issue. We will raising a support ticket.

Comment: Does the redirect work if you get rid of the Insert function?

Comment: No, it won't work. Currently we added a workaround using JavaScript to redirect.